# Why do the Liberator's personal weapons stop the user from having multiple weapons

Tags: blakes-7

In Blake's 7, when Roj and Avon discover the cache of hand weapons in the liberator (the ones with the curly telephone cables) they discover that if they pick up one, the other's appear hot to them.

Did this ever become a plot feature?

Comment: Great to see a **Blakes 7** question but you seem to be asking two separate questions. I suggest you separate them: *"Why do the liberator's personal weapons stop the user from having multiple weapons?"* and *"Did this ever become a plot feature?"*

Comment: They are linked. As I don't recall the hot gun ever ever being used. But it could have been and thus the explanation for it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's never explained why the Liberator only allows 1 weapon per person, only (in pseudo science) how:

Episode [Cygnus Alpha](http://webhome.idirect.com/~cgorman/b7/scripts/timesquad.htm):,

```
AVON: Single function isomorphic response.
JENNA: What?
BLAKE: I think he means it'll only let us have one gun each.
AVON: Well, it certainly gives one a feeling of independence.
BLAKE: What does?
AVON: This. (points gun at Blake)
```

As to it being a plot point, not really.

I recall (though can't currently find it referenced in the scripts), Avon bypasses the security early on in the first season, when he takes control of the Liberator's systems, allowing multiple weapons to be help by any one person.

Answer (score 3):

I believe in the episode "Redemption" the guns all became hot and impossible to touch by the crew as the System re established control of the Liberator

Answer (score 1):

the weapon limiter was never used as a plot feature beyond the episode "spacefall". Apparently Avon disengaged the heating feature so that more than one gun could be drawn by one person.